# How to decode PHP array

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array named '$mails' which contains the result of mysql_fetch_array()

print_r($mails) gives me the result as follows

```
  Array ( [0] => 1 [id] => 1 [1] => jojo [name] => jojo [2] => user@gmail.com [email]  => user@gmail.com [3] => fdh [msg] => fdh [4] => General Question [subject] => General Question )
```

how can I retrieve data using php foreach method ?
result should be

```
1
jojo
user@gmail.com
fdh
General Question
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to access and use the data within this array?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you really need or want? Maybe it would be better, if you fetch only an associative array from your result.

Comment: I want to display the content in HTML page. I got the resultset from mysql and retuned this result set as such to HTML page. Now I want to extract the data from this.

Comment: foreach ($mails as $key => $value) {
   echo $value;
    }  $mails is the resultset. This foreach gives the result as                                                                    11jojojojoitzmejojo@gmail.comitzmejojo@gmail.comfdhfdhGeneral QuestionGeneral Question . were the contect is repeating. I want only 1 set of data.

Comment: Are you asking about how an `Array` work? Not sure what you mean with `decode PHP array`.

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity. Now I edited , hope problem is clear to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with this

```
$n = sizeof($emails)/2;

for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++)
{
   echo $emails[$i]."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use mysql_fetch_assoc but mysql is depreciated so mysqli or prepared statements is the standard now.

do a foreach loop

```
foreach($mails as $k => $v)
{

echo $k . ": " . $v . "<br />"; // add html mark up if need be here, iterates array and displays it in order

}
```

Code output:

```
id: 1
name:  jojo
email: user@gmail.com
msg: fdh
subject: General Question
```